# Incrementing and Decrementing Values in the UpDown Control in C++ WINAPI

Tags: c++, winapi, updown

Today I am faced with an issue of incrementing and decrementing my updown controls in WINAPI.

I have an image below of my updown control. It is buddied with an edit control

[image: screenshot]

What I would want this control is to increment/decrement by 1 respectively when the arrow keys are pressed. I have tried the style: UDS_ARROWKEYS, but it doesn't work leading me to believe there's another method to solve this problem.

I have written a snippet to reproduce the image above.

```
HWND edit1 = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE, L"EDIT", L"250", WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | ES_CENTER | ES_NUMBER...
HWND upDown1 = CreateWindow(L"MSCTLS_UPDOWN32", L"", WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | UDS_ALIGNRIGHT...

SendMessage(upDown1, UDM_SETBUDDY, reinterpret_cast<WPARAM>(edit1), static_cast<LPARAM>(NULL));
```

Answer (score 5):

Enable the `UDS_SETBUDDYINT` style on the Up-Down control:

[Up-Down Control Styles](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb759885.aspx)

> **UDS_SETBUDDYINT**
>  
>   Causes the up-down control to set the text of the buddy window (using the `WM_SETTEXT` message) when the position changes. The text consists of the position formatted as a decimal or hexadecimal string.

This is stated in the [Up-Down Control Overviews](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh298429.aspx) documentation:

[About Up-Down Controls](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb759889.aspx)

> **Up-Down Control Styles**
>   ...
>   **An up-down control with the `UDS_SETBUDDYINT` style sets the caption of its buddy window whenever the current position changes.** The control inserts a thousands separator between every three digits of a decimal string unless the `UDS_NOTHOUSANDS` style is specified. If the buddy window is a list box, an up-down control sets its current selection instead of its caption.
>
> You can specify the `UDS_ARROWKEYS` style to provide a keyboard interface for an up-down control. If this style is specified, the control processes the up and down arrow keys. The control also subclasses the buddy window so that it can process these keys when the buddy window has the focus.
>   ...